# How to attach a property to string?

Tags: haxe

Can I do something like this in haxe:

```
trace ("Blue".description);
trace ("Green".description);
trace ("Red".description);
```

then, somewhere add a switch based on string value to return different description for each case?

I saw people using this for localization, like `"Car".i18()`

Any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [static extensions](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-static-extension.html).

Basically it allows you to pretend static methods are member methods, but the first argument is the object you're operating on.

In your example

```
class ColorDescriptions {
    static public function description( color:String ) {
        return switch (color) {
            case "red": "passionate";
            case "blue": "calm";
            case "green": "environmentally friendly";
            default: "unknown colour";
        };
    }
}
```

And then:

```
using ColorDescriptions; // Use static methods from `ColourDescriptions` as mixins
...
trace( "red".description() ); // "passionate"
```

This only works with methods/functions, not properties.  So `"red".description()` is possible, but `"red".description` is not.

Comment: No worries!  I appreciate the good questions, everything you ask is something that now shows up with an answer whenever people search google with the same question :)  Happy haxing!

Comment: Is it possible to use Mixins in numbers? like 9.en() ??

Comment: yeah of course !
you just have to type your method's argument
//in NumTools.hx
static function add(n:Int,plus:int){return n+plus;}
//
using NumTools;
trace( 2.add(3));

http://try.haxe.org/#cc959